# Python Upload CSV to Sharepoint Online : Incorrect Formatting after Upload

Tags: python, csv, sharepoint, formatting

Using python, I'm uploading a csv file to Sharepoint online. I'm able to get the file to the Sharepoint site document list, but when I open the CSV file it is incorrectly formatted.

```
Example: 

Source file: 
"FirstName", "LastName", "Date"
"John", "Smith", "08-09-1990"
"Jane", "doe", "01-02-2010"

Destination Sharepoint file: (after upload to Sharepoint online) 
"FirstName"\ "LastName"\ "Date"\ "John"\ "Smith"\ "08-09-1990"\ "Jane"\ "doe"\ "01-02-2010"
```

The destination Sharepoint file ends up having a modified delimiter and all of the data is parsed to a single row. I believe the single row parsing is due to the change from a "," delimiter to a "" delimiter.

How can I keep the source file formatting with rows/columns? Below is the code that I'm using.

```
#Connect to Sharepoint
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url_shrpt)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username_shrpt, password_shrpt):
  ctx = ClientContext(url_shrpt, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print('Authenticated into sharepoint as: ',web.properties['Title'])

else:
  print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
##### ---- ####  

#Upload the files
try:
        #list all of the files in the folder
    
    
        for file in fileNames:
            #Open individual files and read content
            readFile = open(file_name + file, 'r')
            data = readFile.read()

            #Set the destination path for the files to be sent
            remotepath = r'Shared Documents/Folder/SubFolder/'+file
    
            #List the director, then split the files to get the file name
            dir, name = os.path.split(file)
            file = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(dir).upload_file(remotepath, data).execute_query()
            print("File has been uploaded to Sharepoint")

            #close the file so it can be archived
            readFile.close()
    
    
except Exception as err:
        print("Something went wrong with writing files: " + str(err))
```